# Contact and Separation

Tags: metaphysics, quantification

If we say for argument that two objects are in contact withstanding physical properties of atoms that prohibit actual contact at that level of observation.

From classical observation of the world if one of the objects has a force exerted upon it in an opposing direction to that of its contact with the other object.

Just exactly how much time has to occur for them to become separate or to put it another way just what degree of spacial measurement affords there separation.

Without counter arguing any measure of time or measurement, if you grasp the point I'm trying to propose.

Just what scale of measure returns itself an appropriate quantity in this scenario or is it a question of the logic and definition of the language I am using to give a picture of the scenario?

Comment: This is a physics question, not a philosophy question.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker: Theres an argument relevant to this question in Aristotles works. I'll let some else find the relevant extract.

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker that maybe the case but the tag quantification was listed in philosophy. This was primarily the question I was raising as to the nature of quantification. In this scenario you cannot return any quantity because of infinite division which results in an absence of any quantity in the presence of the scenario. Is it half a second a fraction an inch. Or is the logic of the language used in the picture offer an easy solution to the proposition, and I have an incorrect understanding. Conceptually I don't think it is solely in the realm of physics my friend never the less :)

Comment: So? We've learned a few things since Aristotle's time. His ideas on science are suitable only for laughing at.

Comment: Still, this is simple physics. If objects A and B are in "contact" (for some suitable definition of contact--say, within the range of van Der Waals forces), and some force is applied to one side of object A, then the earliest point in time at which object B can feel any effect is the time of the speed of light across object A, since no effect can propogate faster than light. In reality, it will probably be slower.

Comment: I posed a question as to the nature of causality and the response suggested the nature of action and reaction or cause and effect were independent of time but without any firm assertion of simultaneity, which philosophically opposes Einstein theory and its consequence. Even given your argument it only returns a measure of time to the effect on the other object and not to what degree separation is, unless you fall in to the logic of the language and its negation, and separation being any measure and simply an absence of contact.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Actually it’s the speed of sound in the object.

Comment: No, sound is a wave of spatial deformation, but there are other effects that might propogate through object A, for example, an electrical current. The speed of light is the theoretical limit of all such effects.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker if the speed of light is the limit and an effect is from a simultanous cause, even causality forces concepts of time in its definition and use. A perception that can see time as a dimension relative to it would be able to percieve the determinate nature of cause and effect and its simultaneity and observe every event of that causality from its perception, and if causality is independent of time then every event is within a singular point whose only dimension comes from an observer thats able to percieve a path within that zero point which will be non linear.

Comment: "Simultaneous" has no meaning to events outside each other's light-cone.

Comment: Yes Einstein propose the passage of time they observe is a consequence of there own perception and they have their own singularity. Light cones and its notion are a consequence of time and events if they are singularly observed cannot be communicated of there presence because they cannot be affirmed by that communication because of the logic, it renders that argument to the logic of which formed it and simultaneity to have no definition outside of a singular incommunicable definition and the perception that develops it. But we are having this conversation with a degree of simultaneity.

Comment: If you reduce the continnous to be a subject of value at an instant then surely it proposes the discrete nature in the concept of value and the continuous to be discretionary in nature from a sample of it. Separation could be a product of the discretionary basis of dimension and time were similarly discrete and you could answer my question based upon this premise of a spacial and temporal nature in the illusion of the continnuos being a product of discretion which returns an absolute quantity and accounts for immesurable degree.